# Google Maps in Meteor App

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, meteor, google-maps-api-3

I want to add a geo- location feature into my meteor app, it shows only the error, I have searched here, but could not find any suitable answer. Also I have added `meteor add mdg:geolocation` package

```
 <!--html part-->
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=false"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">initMap = function(){
        console.log("*** Map  Start ********")
                var mapOptions = {
                  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                  zoom: 8,
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
                    mapOptions);
                console.log("*** Map  end ********")
        }


    </script> 
    </head>


  <template name="map">  
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </template>
```

> client/main.js

```
if(Meteor.isClient)
{
     Template.map.rendered = function(){

    var successHandler = function(position) {
      Session.set('lat', position.coords.latitude);
      Session.set('lon', position.coords.longitude);
    };

    var errorHandler = function (errorObj) {
      alert(errorObj.code + ": " + errorObj.message);

      Session.set('lat',22.0546106 );
      Session.set('lon',88.3939791);

    };

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        successHandler, errorHandler,
        {timeout: 20000, enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 10000});
  }

  Tracker.autorun(function(){
    initMap();
  });
}


if (Meteor.isServer) {
         Meteor.startup(function () {
        // code to run on server at startup
        });
        }

        initMap = function() {
        console.log("***** Start *****");
        var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(Session.get('lat'),Session.get('lon')),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
        console.log("***** End *****");
        }

Router.route('map');
```

> client/main.css

```
#map-canvas { 
width: 100%; 
height: 300px; 
}
```

> Error shown in the console

`"*** Map  Start ********" map:9
TypeError: a is null js:80
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. map
"Google Maps API warning: InvalidKey https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#invalid-key" util.js:210
"Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required" util.js:210`

Comment: It looks like there is an error in Google Maps API code, which appears to be minified (evidence by the fact is says "TypeError: a is null js:80".  I would try to switch to a non-minified version of Google Maps and see if you can get a better description as to what the problem is.  Otherwise we are all mostly shooting in the dark.  Or, see if there is an NPM package or Meteor package that you can use.  I used an NPM package for React that seemed to work pretty well.

Comment: So, what shall I do now?? Pl help!!

Comment: Well, I gave several suggestions.  What you have provided is not really of much use to help.  If you are using the straight APIs, then maybe try using the non-minified versions so we can see a better error message.  Or, try using a pre-built package of some kind that might have a decent example on how to use it.